# Comparando variáveis em uma query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom preciso criar um if para verificar se o campo vindo do POST está vazio ou não, caso se estiver devo setar null, caso não eu seto o valor que veio na variavel.

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_CLIENTES_PF (COD_IDENT_CLIEN, TXT_NATUR_CLIEN, 

TXT_NACIO_CLIEN, DAT_NASCI_CLIEN, TXT_OCUPA_ATUAL, TXT_NOMEX_CLUBE, TXT_ALTUR_CLIEN, TXT_PESOX_CLIEN, TXT_ENDER_TWITR, TXT_ENDER_FACEB, TXT_ENDER_YOUTB, TXT_DATAX_ADMIS, TXT_GOSTO_CLIEN, TXT_NGOST_CLIEN, COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL) VALUES";
$query2 .= "('$COD_IDENT_ULTIM_CLIEN','$naturalidade','$nacionalidade', "(strcmp($dtnasc, "") == 0 ? 'null' : "'" . $dtnasc . "'")" '$dtnasc','$ocupacao','$clube','$altura','$peso','$twitter','$facebook','$youtube','$desde','$gostede','$naogostade', '$usurLoga', now())";
```

Comment: if (isset($_POST['nome']) { faça alguma coisa; } else { faça outra coisa; }

Comment: não funciona, para o que eu quero, quero testar a variavel, olha minha query la

Comment: if (isset($_POST['nome']) { $query2 = "bla bla bla"; } else { $query2 = null; }

Comment: Não é isso que quero, olha meu exemplo, o erro está nas aspas, não estou sabendo coloca-las

Comment: Cara, voce nao quer verificar se um POST esta vazio ou não? pra que você quer fazer isso no meio da query se você pode simplificar do jeito que te falei?
No caso eu recomendaria você usar PDO porque esse negocio de armazenar query dentro de variável não é mais recomendado.

Comment: NA verdade não é bem o post, é variável.

Comment: então use if (!is_null($variavel)) {# code...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função `isset()` e um `if` ternário.

```
$variavel = (isset($_POST["variavel"])?$_POST["variavel"]:"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o problema é que você esta passando a variável mesmo depois de já ter setado o parâmetro (null ou dtnasc):

```
"(strcmp($dtnasc, "") == 0 ? 'null' : "'" . $dtnasc . "'")" '$dtnasc',
```

acredito que dessa maneira deva funcionar:

```
".(strcmp($dtnasc, "") == 0 ? 'null' : $dtnasc)."
```

Mas acho que como outros já explicaram, é melhor e mais compreensível para uma futura manutenção, dessa maneira:

```
if(isset($_POST['dtnasc'])){$dtnasc = $_POST['dtnasc'];}else{$dtnasc = NULL;}
```

Depois de feito isso, só jogar a variável na query.

Comment: Está dando erro @jhonathan machado

Comment: `".(strcmp($dtnasc, '') == 0 ? 'null' : '\''.$dtnasc.'\'')."`

A função strcmp tem que ser feita com aspas simples, explicando de uma forma simples é porque se não ela acaba "saindo" da função, porque a string está sendo feita através de aspas duplas, e quando não for nulo  tem que haver o `'\''` porque ele é parâmetro da query assim como `'$nacionalidade', '$naturalidade'` etc... Acho que isso irá resolver seu problema...